# Comparing two ranges of numbers and say if the first overlaps the second

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm new to Excel and I need to use it for a scientific paper.
I'm trying to optimize my database data gathering workflow.

My file http://cid-1662ba2be7d0ee4e.skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?resid=1662BA2BE7D0EE4E!144

I need to compare the range created by the columns "Start" and "End" to the different ranges inside the yellow square and output, in the "co-localization" column, if the Start-End range overlaps just the first value (Yes - Start), just the second value (Yes - End), overlaps both (Yes - both) or is just contained (Yes - Contained). If none of the conditions is met, just output "No".

Is this too complex for Excel?

Thanks!

btw: I tagged this question Excel 2010, because that's what I use at home, but if you know how to do this in earlier version I would gladly accept that answer too.

Comment: I would love to help, but I don't really want to put in my email address to look at the file you posted. Did you know that you can post files on Microsoft Web Apps (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/) for no cost? From there you can share them publicly and people don't need to login or provide info to download your file. If you post it up there you may get a few more people (including myself) to help you out.

Comment: Done ;) I didn't know about that service. Thanks

Comment: If an answer works for you, you should accept it.  See [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: There you go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution:

First a small change to your sheet layout (values in range F2:G11)

```
From            To  
                    0  
        0    27800000  
 34400000    46500000  
 51000000   102000000  
107000000   117600000  
120700000   153300000  
154800000   163800000  
171200000   174300000  
184000000   247200000  
999999999   999999999
```

Add 4intermediate result columns (i've used I, J, K, L)

add Formulas

```
I2    =MATCH(A2,$F$2:$F$11,1)      
J2    =MATCH(A2,$G$2:$G$11,1)+1
K2    =MATCH(B2,$F$2:$F$11,1)
L2    =MATCH(B2,$G$2:$G$11,1)+1
```

Copy these down for all rows in your data

Formula Co-localization Cell

```
D2   =IF(AND(I2=J2,I2=K2,I2=L2),"Yes - Contained",IF(AND(I2=J2,K2=L2),"Yes - Both",IF(I2=J2,"Yes - Start",IF(K2=L2,"Yes - End","No"))))
```

To cope with the additional criteria for "Yes - Middle", add another criteria to the formula to test for spanning a from/to range

```
D2 =IF(AND(I2=J2,I2=K2,I2=L2),"Yes - Contained",IF(AND(I2=J2,K2=L2),"Yes - Both",IF(I2=J2,"Yes - Start",IF(K2=L2,"Yes - End",IF(AND(I2+1=J2,K2+1=L2,I2<K2),"Yes - Middle","No")))))
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this does it, but could you explain me why are the extra lines "0" and "999..." needed?

Comment: to avoid the `MATCH`'s returning n/a errors for 'To' < 2780000 and incorrect results From > 18400000 or To > 247200000 (i should have mentioned, the extra last value needs to be > any possible From/To value)

Comment: @chris neilsen: Thanks for the explanation. But isn't the 999.. cell useless since your formula doesn't select it? (still works flawlessly though)

Comment: btw: it's funny.. the formulas won't work in google docs (they output n/a) but work everywhere else. Just a side note, no big deal.

Comment: @chris neilsen: I found a situation where your formula isn't working: the case when a sequence begins and ends outside the F2:G11 data set, but crosses it (begin>...F2:G11 data..>end). As of now this results in a "No" answer, when maybe "Yes - middle" was more appropriate. I didn't ask for this in my original request, this is a question that has risen after having put your great formula to work. How could I do this?

Comment: Have edited answer to include the additional 'Yes - Middle' criteria